# What are the differences between a struct People and an array People[]?

Tags: solidity

```
    uint256 favoriteNumber; //this is at index 0 inside the struct
        string name; // this is index 1 in the struct
    }
    
    People[] public people; // type of variable "People[]", vissibility of variable and name of variable
    //People public person = People({favoriteNumber: 2, name: "Patrick"});
    
    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber; // type of variable is "mapping" string name is gonna be mapped to the fav. number
    // from the name get the favorineNumber. map the name to the fav. number on the list
    
    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
     
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256){
        return favoriteNumber;
    }
    
    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public { // you can store an obj in memory or in storage. memory is local "storage" is is the whole contract
         people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name)); //1st index of People is _favoriteNumber the 2nd is _name; 
         //we are pushing the People object into our people array
         nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber; // the string _name will be mapped to uint256 which is the fav number
     }
```

I'm confused on how is the struct named People related to the array People[]?

[image: code sample]

Answer (score 0):

From the current [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html?highlight=arrays#arrays) :

> The type of an array of fixed size k and element type T is written as
> T[k], and an array of dynamic size as T[].

In your specific example :

```
People[] public people;
```

Simply creates a dynamic array containing items of type People, where People happens to be a user defined struct.

Think of a struct as a user-defined type that could contain (almost) anything. While arrays are ordered collections of Items.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but the code just confused you by using the name People twice. To make it easier to understand just add an "s" to the second people like this:
People[] public peoples;
or People[] public person;